# Using minted package on Ubuntu: .w18 file not found error

Tags: xetex, ubuntu, minted, pygments

I am trying to run the following code through XeLaTeX, using the -shell-escape option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The file is named guess.tex and the error I get is:

```
! Package catchfile Error: File `guess.w18' not found.

See the catchfile package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.93     \CatchFileDef\@tempa{\ip@file}{}
```

If I remove \usepackage{minted} it runs fine.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and I have tried this both with the texlive version in the ubuntu repositories and with texlive 2014 (through the net installer). My version of pygments is 2.0.2.

Comment: Are you using the TeXlive version from the official Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Yes, this is why I mentioned purging. I will edit my post.

Comment: If you are going to use the most newer tools from the TeX world I recommend you to install TeXlive from its website not from the repository.

Comment: Thanks, I will try going that way too. I am just wondering if anyone can reproduce the problem with this minimal example I have provided. It is striking to me that I do not actually _use minted code, I simply include the package.

Comment: I have now downloaded and installed texlive 2014 using the net installer (instructions from [http://askubuntu.com/questions/486170/upgrade-from-tex-live-from-2013-to-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04]). It still results in an identical error. This seems very odd to me, the input file is as minimal as it gets, it simply includes the minted package.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I was compiling with `lualatex`. I could solve it by switching to `xelatex` (both with `-shell-escape`).

Answer (score 12):

It seems that I am facing exactly the same problem. It does not make any sense for me. However, it only worked for me when I removed the spaces from the name of tex file. The original name had some spaces like this "programming language.tex" and I transformed into "programing.tex.

Why I tried this?

I tried to execute

```
pdflatex -shell-escape programing language.tex
```

and it complained about finding "programming". So I tried this and it worked.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and kile as a tex editor.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem, and got rid of it by merely closing the command line (I use it to compile my documents), opening another one, doing a clean and recompiling everything.

If you use an editor provided with a *compile* option, try closing and re-opening it.

**EDIT:** A temporary solution I found was to reboot the computer when encountering such an error, but it's pretty strange indeed.

Comment: Do you experience the same problems when using `pdflatex --shell-escape` instead of `xelatex --shell-escape`? With `pdflatex` it seems it works.